# Running script to copy file to all users

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I'm trying to get a script that adds the Outlook 2013 icon to the taskbar of all users and I can't get it to work. I've found a script online that adds the icon but I can't get it to be ran automatically through PSEXEC so I can fully automate the process.

The GOAL is to have PSEXEC search c:\users and find all usernames and run this command under that username.

```
for /f "delims=|" %f in ('dir /b /a:-dhr c:\users') do "\\server\installs\microsoft\office2013\scripts\tbcustom.bat"
```

If I run the tbcustom.bat locally on the PC it works as it should, and I've tried changing things around and I can't figure it out.

EDIT: The initial issue is fixed by using the %%f instead. Now it's still not doing what it's supposed to. I'm not sure what I am missing, I want this to run through all user accounts but simply copying the icon to the folder path doesn't work (guessing this is a known issue with Microsoft).

tbcustom.bat:

```
:: Set Environment
@ECHO OFF
CLS
TITLE Taskbar Customization Tool
COLOR 3f
PROMPT $s
SET UsrPinTBar="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar"
:: *** Usage - Pin.vbs
:: *** WScript.exe "%~dp0\%~dp0\Pin.vbs" [drive:][path]filename [Argument]
:: *** [Arguments] = 0 1 2
:: *** 0 = Unpin from Taskbar
:: *** 1 = Pin to Taskbar
:: *** 2 = Install
::  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
:: *** REMOVE WINDOWS MEDIA PLAYER ***
WScript.exe "%~dp0\Pin.vbs" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Windows Media Player.lnk" 0
IF EXIST "%UsrPinTBar%\Windows Media Player.lnk" DEL /q /f "%UsrPinTBar%\Windows Media Player.lnk"
:: *** ADD OUTLOOK***
WScript.exe "%~dp0\Pin.vbs" "%ProgramFiles% (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Outlook.exe" 1
GOTO EOF
::  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
:EOF
EXIT
```

Comment: If you run the first codw from a bat you have to double `%` : `for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b /a:-dhr c:\users')...` .

Comment: That fixed that issue, but it's still not running completely. (locally it runs fine but remotely it does not complete). I tried adding pauses to the script but it still just closes at a certain point and I can't see the error/message.

Comment: Wher do you use %%f in your `FOR`loop ? I think it should be : `"\\server\installs\Microsoft\Office2013\Scripts\tbcustom.bat" "%%f"

Comment: Tried changing that still no luck. Says `%%f is unexpected at this time.`